# Why was there a battle at Jakku?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Why was there a battle around Jakku?

Presumably the star destroyer and scattered imperial vehicles/fighters ended up there as a result of a battle.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*The Lost Stars* book covers it, as well as "Battlefront" game, and summarized well [in Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_Jakku)

> The Battle of Jakku occurred one year and four days after the Battle of Endor between the forces of the New Republic and the Galactic Empire. With the rebels aiming to **capture a critical sector in the galactic war** and **receiving intelligence of an Imperial weapons facility on the planet**. the Empire readily dismissed the notion of a rebel victory and sent a large portion of its now militarily exhausted Navy to combat the rebels over control of the planet in a battle that could change the course of the war.